# how to catch a file on the rest api controller and what method to send it with Postman

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, postman

I do not know how to catch the file on the rest api controller and what method to send it to Postman, please help me will be very grateful)

> Body

[image: postman body]

> Headers

[image: postman headers]

> Controller

[image: controller]

Comment: Don't image' code. Show Code and header, body Parameter.

Comment: `@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file`  and Post RequestMethod may be used in Postman

Comment: and need class MultipartFile to configure?

Answer (score 0):

To post a file through postman you need a method something like :

```
@PostMapping(path = "/post", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("message")String message, @RequestParam("subject")Integer subject ){
//You can then get any info about file like : 
System.out.println(file.getName()); 
System.out.println(file.getOriginalName()); 
System.out.println(file.getContentType()); 
}
```